# Rolling time window. Loop for vector(i) in Matlab

Tags: loops, vector, return

i have a vector (276,1) with monthly S&P500 returns. What i need are 127 vectors with only a timeframe of 150 months. So my entire data is from Jan 91 - Dez 14. I want vector1 = vector(1:150), vector2 = vector(2:151), .... vector127=vector(127:276).

I tried this in MATLAB, but an error ocurred.

SP500 = xlsread('Datastream.xlsx', 2, 'C3:C278')

n = 276

l = 150;

Returns(t) = zeros(l,1);

for t = 1:(n-l+1)

```
Returns(t) = SP500(t:(t+l-1))
```

end

thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is in Octave, and with a random vector in sp500, but may do what you are looking for:

```
>> n=276;l=150;
>> sp500=rand(1,n);
>> Returns=zeros(n-l+1,l);
>> for t=1:(n-l+1);Returns(t,:)=sp500(t:t+l-1);endfor;
```

(though the Returns array might be the transpose of what you are looking for, but the code does not care if sp500 is a row or column vector)

Comment: thx. But this gives me one matrix (127x150) with all the correct returns for the 127 time frames. What i want is a multidemnsional vector "returns", i can calculate with. For example i want to calculate the mean i am just typing mean = mean(returns(t)), and then calculates the mean for every 127 time frames. Or i want to fit a distribution to the returns i dont have to type 127 times distrfit blabla, but only once.

Comment: Sounds like you want to put them in a [cell array](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html)